# Returning custom status code is not working in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am a newcomer in ASP.Net Web API world. Sorry if this is a foolish question.

I have the following api method -

```
[Route("api/v1/Location/Create")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Create(Location location)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    return Ok();
}


public class Location
{
    public int MCC { get; set; }
    public int MNC { get; set; }
    public int LAC{ get; set; }
    public int CellId { get; set; }
}
```

If I send a string value from client, it still returns `StatusCode 200`.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your class as follows-

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Location
{
    [Required()]
    public int MCC { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public int MNC { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public int LAC{ get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public int CellId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't put any data annotations on your location class.
Try it adding `[Required]` data annotation one of property.

Answer (score 1):

`ModelState.IsValid` is checking the data model validation when each filed is annotated by `[Required]`.